# Get current page URL and append it to Facebook Share link (with javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I've been trying really hard to make the Facebook share button work, but no luck. I'd like to have the same code on ALL my pages, so I need to be able to dynamically get the current page url and append it to the Facebook share URL.

The best I could come up with is the following:

```
<a href="" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=' + 
encodeURIComponent(location.href))">Share this page</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/08x2sufs/2/

However, as you can see from the jsFiddle demo, the link does take us to a Facebook share page, but there is no page to share.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is quite likely that this is due to the fact that you are trying to share the URL `https://fiddle.jshell.net/08x2sufs/2/show/` here, and Facebook’s scraper can’t read that URL. Try it under “real” conditions, on a page you know the FB scraper can read properly. (And if in doubt, use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to find out.)

Answer (score 6):

I would use the following approach:

```
<a href="" id="fb_share">Share this page</a>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        fb_share.href ='http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href); 
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: You just need to add var fbShareLink = document.getElementById('fb-share-link');

Answer (score 0):

```
$Url = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
$Url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo $Url; ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small">

<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $Url; ?>&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>
```

Comment: Oh, with java, my bad. Oh well, this might help some other person. ;)

Comment: Hi Graham and thanks for the contribution! Can you please add some explanation to your answer? Indeed, also the clarification of the coding language used would be useful for some future readers. Thank you and keep on stackoverflowing!

Comment: it helped me! thanks haha. using php here